# Check Process wfcrun32.exe is running

Tags: vbscript, windows-shell

I'm looking for a VBScript that when a user logons onto windows and the VBScript is placed in the startup, it will check if process wfcrun32.exe is running under that user that logged in. 
If the process wfcrun32.exe is running in task manger then do nothing, 
If the process is not running it will continue on with the script below.

objShell.Run """C:\Program Files (x86)\Citrix\ICA Client\wfcrun32.exe"" ""C:\Launch.ica"""

Thanks
Derek

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
Option Explicit

Const PROC = "wfcrun32.exe"
Dim wmi,col

Set wmi = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")
Set col = wmi.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Process where caption='" & PROC &"'")

If col.Count = 0 Then
  With CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    .Run """C:\Program Files (x86)\Citrix\ICA Client\wfcrun32.exe"" ""C:\Launch.ica"""
  End With
End If
WScript.Quit
```

Comment: Thanks Jobbo, Is there a way in the code to only end the wfcrun.exe for the user that is logged in. I have a feeling that other users will be logged in running wfcrun.exe

Comment: There's nothing in there about ending a process. This will start wfcrun32.exe for the user that is running the script. That user would need elevated privileges to end _someone else's_ wfcrun32.exe. Wouldn't the process be killed when the user logs out?

Comment: Sorry - you are correct, i don't want the script to end the process(wfcrun32.exe) but there will be multiple users logging in and I don't want the script to see wfcrun32.exe under another users account causing the process wfcrun32.exe not to run. The process will not be killed on log off.